# Getting off a lift problem

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $21$ people get onto a lift at level $0$. Assuming that everyone gets off the life at some level between $1$ and $10$ (both inclusive). In how many ways can people get off so that atleast one gets off at each level

Here we're looking for number of surjections from set of people with cardinality $21$ to set of levels with cardinality $10$.

So the answer should be $S(21,10)\cdot 10!$ where $S$ is Stirling's number of second kind.

Is this correct?

Comment: looks stars and bars to me

Comment: @pooja People are not identical

Comment: There is the question of whether the people themselves are distinguishable.  Clearly, the floors themselves should be distinguishable, and it is common to consider people as distinguishable as well.  As such it will *not* be a stars and bars problem like @pooja suggests.  Your answer involving stirling numbers of the second kind is the correct answer.  An equivalent answer could be arrived at via inclusion-exclusion (*which is one of the ways of deriving a formula for stirling numbers of second kind in the first place*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer involving stirling numbers of the second kind is correct and is among the common problem types given in the [twelve-fold way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way#case_s).